# Removing something on Collision?

Tags: xna, c#, collision-detection, xna-4.0

I have my collision detection code working so how would I tell my HealthPickup to disappear when my Player collides with it? I haven't played around with it yet but I think I may have to somehow remove the hitbox and stop calling the `Draw()` function (at least for my HealthPickup anyway)

Please note I am a novice and have not really dealt with XNA before.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of entities or a list of potions which you loop through, you can simply remove the entity from the list. This should be standard practice anyway, as this makes it extremely easy to add more items without assigning loads of variables.

Answer (score 0):

If your Health pickup is an object, you could set it to null if you detect a collision. The garbage collector will do the rest for you. But don't try to reference that object after it is null because it will give your a runtime error.

```
if(player.collides(healthpotion))
{
 player.health += 100;
 healthpotion = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. My code uses rectangle intersects to detect collisions so it would be more something like this: `HealthPickup.Hitbox.Intersects(Player.Hitbox)` would that still work?

Comment: Most likely, yes. You should null out your HealthPickup object. But don't try to check intersection with it after you've nulled it, so probably you should also add a check if(HealthPickup!=null) then update/draw/do anything with it. ;)

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll try that out when I get home.

Comment: The null didn't work :(
Also, after a few seconds of running my FPS deteriorates until my game crashes with a Win32Exception (The operation completed successfully) I have no clue how that is a bad thing but it highlights one of my many `Game game = new Game();` objects. EDIT: Fixed that now. Also my object doesn't disappear when I've nulled it.

Comment: Nulling doesn't work for me, sorry :( what I did was edit the rectangle so it was offscreen and at size `0, 0`. Effectively removing it.

Comment: Nulling should work if everything what you want to remove is contained by the object which is nulled and you don't dereference that anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit to Rokk's answer.

Chances are, since you say you are new to XNA, that you use the `GameComponentList`, in the `Game` class, known as `Components`.

If so, then the solution is simple. Just make sure you can reach that `Components` list from your collision code and use `Components.Remove(healthPickup);`. Your game will now stop drawing it and the garbage collector will (if you aren't referencing it from some other spot) clean it up for you.

If you are not using that Component list I was talking about, then it depends on your code. This is also where I refer you back to Rokk's answer.

---

EDIT: Some examples and explenation supporting my comment.

In my comment I mentioned a `DrawableGameComponent`. You mentioned that nothing happened. A guess I could make for why nothing is happening is that you might miss the calls to the base class in your game class. Example below.

```
public class Game1 : Game
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Components.Add(new HealthPickup(/* constructor arguments here */));
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //Next line will call Update(GameTime) on all Components in Components.
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(/* Your color here */);

        //Next line will call Draw(GameTime) on all DrawableComponents in Components. 
        base.Draw(gameTime);;
    }
}
```

The `base.something` calls I made in both `Draw()` and `Update()` make sure that XNA will call the `Draw()` of each `DrawableGameComponent` and the `Update()` of each `GameComponent` (including `DrawableGameComponent`).

Then your HealthPickup should have the following:

```
public class HealthPickup : DrawableGameComponent
{
    //Ignoring constructor and other component stuff for the sake of an example.

    //Adding this component to the GameComponentList causes this function
    //to be called during every update cycle.
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Update(gameTime);

        //TODO update logic here...
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Draw(gameTime);

        //TODO draw logic here...
    }
}
```

If you have this then HealthPickup should be called every update cycle.

Maybe something nice to read is [this guide](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/xna/pong/). It does not cover classes, but it does cover the XNA basics. It does ignore the Component list so you have to trust the examples above for that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure how to use `GameComponentList` or anything like that. Or where to put it. It's out of my comfort zone but I'm happy to learn it. (actually I'm not even sure where my comfort zone _is_)

Comment: Okay so I've had a go at it and I can't seem to add it to my list. In my `HealthPickup.cs` I have this: `game.Components.Add(this);` (in my `Initialize()` function) but it doens't seem to add it. Do I need to create a list? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you explain "doesn't seem to add it"? Do you get an error message of any kind? Or is just nothing happening? And is your `HeatlhPickup` a `DrawableGameComponent`? (I'll edit my first post as well so be sure to check that out).

Comment: I don't think `HealthPickup` a `DrawableGameComponent`, just a `GameComponent`. And by "doesn't seem to add" I mean that I convert the list to a string and write it to the console. It just has `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameCollection` (something like that) by the way I have fixed this now. I modified the rectangle to be offscreen when it collides.

Comment: The class containing all the content is called GameCollection or something close to that. Turning it into a string does not (as far as I am aware of) show it's content. You can use `Components.Count` (If I am not mistaken, or size/length whatever) to check the number of components in the list.

Comment: Ah okay I'll have a go at that tomorrow then, thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: This isn't really an approach I'd use personally, but whatever floats your boat. My answer involved creating an arbitrary list of entities on game load, and adding and removing from them as you see fit. To update or draw them, I'd loop over them using a foreach.

Comment: I usually maintain my own list as well. And if people have some experience with XNA then I will advice them to create their own lists and do their own update/draw as well. But when someone mentions he/she is a novice, then I advice them to stick with XNA stuff at first to get used to XNA.